# Polygon Triangulation using monotone polygons

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, geometry, triangulation

I have a simple polygon with no holes and it needs to be triangulated into convex polygons for use in a physics engine, and also so I can use those convex polygons for rendering via triangle strips.

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation#cite_note-bkos-0) Wikipedia article shows how monotone polygons can be used to triangulate a polygon. It provides a short description of how it works, but not in enough detail for me to understand. This method seems perfect for what I need, and the [Flash Demo](http://computacion.cs.cinvestav.mx/~anzures/geom/triangulation.php) it links to shows that the algorithm works perfectly for my needs.

I've been searching Google looking for a better explanation on the algorithm, and I can only find libraries or source code that do the triangulation. I would prefer to learn how it works and write my own method, but If I need to use a pre-written library, It will have to do.

Can anyone provide an explanation, or resources for how I can learn how this type of triangulation works?

Comment: Is there a programming language requirement? (please tag if there is)  Are there hardware restrictions - cpu/gpu allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) library provides several implementations of convex decomposition of simple polygons with no holes. Have a look at this [chapter](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Partition_2/Chapter_main.html).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look at Delaunay triangulations: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation). [QHull](http://www.qhull.org/) is the standard implementation. (As a point of reference, MATLAB relies on Qhull: [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/convhulln.html).

If Qhull isn't your thing, try out this [collection](http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/compgeom/code.html).

Comment: Old post, but anyway. It is worth to point out, the Delaunay triangulation is used for a set of points, not for the polygon - which is just an outline